# curl succeeds with oath2 but fails with node.js request

Tags: node.js, curl

The following curl request works properly, returning the authentication token as it should

```
curl POST -s -d "grant_type=password&username=someusername&password=somepassword&client_id=someid&client_secret=somesecret&response_type=token" "someurl"
```

when the equivalent request in node.js fails

```
let url = someurl

var dataString = 'grant_type=password&username=somename&password=somepassword&client_id=someid&client_secret=somesecret&response_type=token';

var options = {
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    body: dataString,
    allow_redirects : true
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
    console.log(error)
    console.log(body)
}

request(options, callback);
```

The error is

```
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"}
```

Which may only be specific to this code.  At any rate, what differences (in default parameters presumably or configuration) could explain this difference.  Note, the programs fails both with and without allow_redirects option, but redirection should be allowed.

This is node v7.10.0 running on macosx and request 2.81.0

Comment: Is it potentially because you're missing headers?

Answer (score 0):

My first assumption would be that you're missing the headers required for your request

```
let url = someurl

var dataString = 'grant_type=password&username=somename&password=somepassword&client_id=someid&client_secret=somesecret&response_type=token';

var options = {
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    body: dataString,
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    allow_redirects: true
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }

    console.log(error)
    console.log(body)
}

request(options, callback);
```

If this isn't correct, let me know and i'll resolve the answer